# Does a DocumentDB Permission Token become invalid when a new one is created?

Tags: permissions, azure-cosmosdb

Resource tokens ["Are recreated when a permission resource is acted upon on by POST, GET, or PUT call."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens)

Is the current resource token the only accepted one? Or does the old one (from the same permission) stay valid for it's intended lifespan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the current resource token the only accepted one?

No.

> Or does the old one (from the same permission) stay valid for it's
>   intended lifespan?

Yes.

I did some tests via postman.

Read my permission and resource token twice then I get the old token and generated new token.(The valid timespan is default 1 hour )

[image]

[image]

Query documents by the two of above resource token successfully.

[image]

[image]